# Auto assigning roles Joined user Discord.net

Tags: vb.net, discord.net

I'm trying to add auto roled new members in Discord server,
For example, I'm using Discord `1.0.1`

`role Name : (Test) / Role ID : (5246771013.....)`

So, I was trying 2 methods, role by `name` and by `id`. None of them works.

```
Private Async Function userJoined(user As SocketGuildUser) As Task
' Welcome message can work good

' time to test auto roled member's while join my server/ let me try with auto roled by ID.

  Dim Role_ID As ULong = 5246771013.....'- Method auto role by ID
 'Dim Role_Name As IGuildUser = "test"  '- Method auto role by name

  Await user.Guild.CurrentUser.Guild.Roles(Role_ID)

End Function
```

But it didn't work as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should really consider updating your version of Discord.Net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By ID :

```
 Dim role = (CType(channell, ITextChannel)).Guild.GetRole(5246771013.....)
```

By Name :

```
 Dim role = (CType(channell, ITextChannel)).Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = "test")
```

then

```
 Await (CType(user, SocketGuildUser)).AddRoleAsync(role)
```